# HTML document styling

Tags: html, document

I have a site where my colleagues need to print off a list off addresses on stickers, which means each address must be contained within a certain sized rectangle (3.5cm*5cm), is there a way to define this in html (in a table perhaps?)?

Comment: This has been answered multiple times on multiple forums. Downvote because of lack of research.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css exclusively for print alone

```
@media print { 
 /* All your print styles go here */

}
```